# SSIS Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column with a length of 250 to database column with a length of 16

Tags: ssis, truncate

In my task of the SSIS package, I read a csv file, I modify one of the columns to eliminate any spaces then I continue with the insert to DB, as you can see from the photo I have the warning described in the title, how do I eliminate it?
I thought (seeing other answers to similar questions) of reducing the length to 16 by clicking in the advanced editor, is this feasible or do I risk losing part of the string if there are spaces?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is just a warning, so if you know the data you are importing is not larger than the table it is being inserted into you can ignore it.  If the data is longer in the file than going into the table, then you need to increase the column length in the DB.

Comment: I agree with @Brad. And since it's a CSV file, I would import it into a spreadsheet, and then you can use a LEN function (or whatever your spreadsheet has) in a separate column, then sort by that column to see what the longest string is. And then pad number that by a comfortable margin, if you fear there may be longer strings down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSIS, the warning about potential truncation occurs when the metadata of a data flow column indicates that it can potentially hold more data than the destination column can accommodate.
In order to remove this warning message, make sure datatype length of the source column should be equal to the datatype length of the destination column. Change the destination column length to 255 for a try or change the data source length to 255.
You can know more about the warnings :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-error-and-message-reference?view=sql-server-ver16